# TSQL: Representation of column and row values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario wherein the data extracted from table is as below

```
EMP_Name Total_Work Work_Classification Work_Type
SAM         10          Shift               1
SAM         20          Shift               2
SAM         40          Shift               3
SAM         80          Day                 NULL
TIM         12          Shift               1
TIM         18          Shift               2
TIM         22          Shift               3
TIM         41          Day                 NULL
John        21          Shift               1
John        17          Shift               2
John        31          Shift               3
John        76          Day                 NULL
```

And the data needs to be represented as below,

```
EMP_Name Total_Work_Day Work_Type1 Work_Type2 Work_Type3
SAM         80          10          20          40
TIM         41          12          18          22
John        76          21          17          31
```

Please help me in getting this issue of representing data using TSQL

Comment: Work_Type3 for SAM, do you mean 40?

Comment: Yes @Xiaosu it is value 40, thank you for bringing this into notice. I shall correct the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results by combining [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) and [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/case-statement-mdx) statements. I ordered by Work_Type1, but you can change or remove the `ORDER BY` based on what you need.

```
SELECT EMP_Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Work_Classification = 'Day' THEN Total_Work ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total_Work_Day',
  SUM(CASE WHEN Work_Type = 1 THEN Total_Work ELSE 0 END) AS 'Work_Type1',
  SUM(CASE WHEN Work_Type = 2 THEN Total_Work ELSE 0 END) AS 'Work_Type2',
  SUM(CASE WHEN Work_Type = 3 THEN Total_Work ELSE 0 END) AS 'Work_Type3'
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY EMP_Name
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN Work_Type = 1 THEN Total_Work ELSE 0 END)
```

Results:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|EMP_Name | Total_Work_Day | Work_Type1 | Work_Type2 | Work_Type3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  SAM    |      80        |    10      |    20      |    40      |
|  TIM    |      41        |    12      |    18      |    22      |
|  JOHN   |      76        |    21      |    17      |    31      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```